# how does Javascript imply convert?

Tags: javascript

recently, i have encountered this question:

`"78.1133" <= "271.7895"`  false

why is it the result? And how implying convertion works in comparing operator`(>, <, >= , <=)`?

thanks.

Comment: why do you think this has something todo with conversion? it's simply string comparison

Comment: Do you need to compare two `number` or `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion only occurs when the two compared entities are of different type... When comparing two strings, there is no conversion to be done. String comparison is made character by character. In your example, 7 is higher than 2 so it returns false.

If you have two numbers stored in strings and need to compare their numerical values, you will need to use `parseFloat()`

Comment: I'd go with `parseFloat` personally

Comment: You're right! I guess I don't play with floats too much :)

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Values are ordered based on the way that they appear in the lexicographic alphabet.

Therefore, `"aaa"` is less than `"aab"`, as the sum of all lexicographic positions for the first string is less than the sum for the second string (imagine adding up the positions in the alphabet - `a` is the first letter, so it is position `1`, thus `"aaa"` is `3`, whereas for `"aab"` it would be `4`).

In lexicographical order, `"1"` is less than `"2"` because it comes before two. Thus, for example, `"11"` is less than `"3"`, because once again we can imagine adding up positions, except this time they are numerical positions rather than alphabetical ones. Using numerical positions, `"1"` is `1` because it is first, so `"11"`'s sum is `2`, whereas `"3"` is `3` because it is third, so it is greater.

This is what is happening here. There is no implication nor conversion.